# Python Web Scraping: trying to control the output

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

Team,

I'm having difficulty getting the output I need when I scrape this web page:

[The Web Page](http://www.forexfactory.com/explorerapi.php?content=positions&do=positions_graph_data&limit=0&interval=M5&&currency=AUDUSD)

**This is what I have:**

```
import urllib2
from html2text import html2text

for line in  html2text(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.forexfactory.com/explorerapi.php?content=positions&do=positions_graph_data&limit=&interval=M5&&currency=AUDUSD").read()).split(','):
if "traders_short"in line:
    print "Traders Short AUDUSD: ", line.split(":")[1].strip(' " ')
if "traders_long" in line:
    print "Traders Long AUDUSD: ", line.split(":")[1].strip(' " ')
```

**This is my output:**

```
Traders Short AUDUSD:  
"114
Traders Long AUDUSD:  88
Traders Long AUDUSD:  88
```

**This is what I would like:**

```
Traders Short AUDUSD: number
Traders Long AUDUSD: number
```

So the problem is:

A) The output is repeating, I only want it to tell me how many traders are short or long ONCE.

B) I can't get rid of the ' " ' in the second line of the output and I want it to sit next to the ' : ' like the next line.

Now here is some more info, this is what the page looks like once its been tidied up with html2text:

```
{"total":"355468"
"positions":[{"timeframe":"M5"
"dateline":79500
"currency_co
de":"AUDUSD"
"short_lots":"22.405234"
"long_lots":"5.1432014"
"traders_short":
"113"
"traders_long":"88"
"weekend":false
"hidden":false
"pos":1
"datetime":{"
year":"1970"
"month":0
"date":"01"
"hour":"22"
"minute":"05"
"estOffset":5}
"l
ots_ratio":18.669667897002
"traders_ratio":43.781094527363
"dummy_lots":-81.33
0332102998
"dummy_traders":-56.218905472637}
{"timeframe":"M5"
"dateline":7980
0
"currency_code":"AUDUSD"
"short_lots":"22.405234"
"long_lots":"5.1432014"
"t
raders_short":"113"
"traders_long":"88"
"weekend":false
"hidden":true
"pos":2

"datetime":1
"lots_ratio":18.669667897002
"traders_ratio":43.781094527363
"dum
my_lots":-81.330332102998
"dummy_traders":-56.218905472637}]
"data_count":1
"h
as_more":true
"interval":"M5"
"currency":"AUDUSD"
"limit":0}
```

Now obviously 'traders short / long' appears **more than once** which is why its printing twice. **But I need it to only print once**.

Any help from the expertise available at this forum would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of treating it like text, use `json.loads()`, which will give you a dict. Then you can get data from it more easily.

Comment: As @kwinkunks says, there is no need to scrape this. It's an API call which is arranged in a JSON format - and python can accept that as nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) because it's so convenient, e.g. it has a built-in `json()` method. You can also easily unpack that long URL into a more readable query dict, and pass that in with the basic URL.

Here's how I would do this:

```
import requests

base_url = "http://www.forexfactory.com/explorerapi.php"
query = {'content': 'positions',
         'do': 'positions_graph_data',
         'limit': '',
         'interval': 'M5',
         'currency': 'AUDUSD'}

r = requests.get(base_url, query)

template = "Traders Short {currency_code}: {traders_short}\n"
template += "Traders Long {currency_code}: {traders_long}\n"

for position in r.json()['positions']:
    if not position['hidden']:
        print(template.format(**position))
```

Importantly, `r.json()` is just a dictionary. I chose to hide the `'hidden'` results, which seem to be duplicates, but of course you can do any processing you like at this point. The result of this is:

```
Traders Short AUDUSD: 116
Traders Long AUDUSD: 88
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As was correctly suggested in the comments, the data is a JSON object.
So, instead of scraping this, try using the `json` module and `urllib.request`(python3).

```
import urllib.request
import json
def get_json(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    js = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

    return js
```

The returned value is then a simple python dictionary, and you can call the keys as you normally would do with a `dict`.

Comment: Of course this doesn't print it once, as op wanted; it is however a simple matter of formatting, after loading the data with the `json` module.